# How to pass the values from one scenario to another scenario in gatling?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have some end to end flow where I have to run a service and pass values to the next scenario. I can print the values inside the scenarios but not able to use them to next scenarios.

I tried to save the values using SaveAs

```
val scn_Token1 ={ scenario("Token1")
    .exec(actionBuilder = http("Token1")
      .post("/getToken")
      .body(StringBody(bdy_Token)).asJson
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(jsonPath("$.Token").exists)
      .check(jsonPath("$..Token")
        .find
        .saveAs("Token")
      )
      .check(jsonPath("$..id")
        .find
        .saveAs("mid")
      )
      .check(jsonPath("$..otp")
        .find
        .saveAs("otp")
      )
    )pause(tnk_token milliseconds)
  }


  val scn_Auth ={ scenario("Authentication")
    .exec(actionBuilder = http("Authentication")
      .post(authServiceUrl)
      .header("Token", "${Token}")
      .header("id", "${id}")
      .header("otp", "${otp}")
      .body(StringBody(bdy_Auth)).asJson
      .check(status.is(200)))
      .pause(tnk_Auth milliseconds)
  }



  setUp(
   scn_Token1.inject(nothingFor(dly_token_first seconds),rampUsers(ucnt_token_first) during (ramp_token_first seconds)).protocols(httpConfToken),
  scn_Auth.inject(nothingFor(dly_Auth seconds),rampUsers(ucnt_Auth) during (ramp_Auth seconds)).protocols(httpConf)
  ).maxDuration(test_duration minutes)
```

I am getting error like

> 'httpRequest-2' failed to execute: No attribute named 'id' is defined
>
> 'httpRequest-2' failed to execute: No attribute named 'Token' is defined

I also tried having wait time for second scenario in a way it will execute after scenario 1 completes. But still it doesn't get the values.

Please note that I don't want the to merge token and Auth in single scenario as it has different configuration. values should be passed from one scenario to another. Please let me know what is going wrong here?

Comment: the scenarios are executed by different users - they do not share a session so nothing generated by Token1 will be in the session for Auth.

Why not just put them both in the same scenario?

Comment: @JamesWarr I wanted to keep token generation(Scenario1) common to all the other scenarios.I  want to keep it running every minute so that all the other APIs take the values from it. So i have it as separate block

Comment: that's not really how gatling users work - if you need to execute Token1 before other scenarios, then you can define it separately, then have it called as part of each of the other scenarios - this way every other scenario will get its own bdy_Auth. So the definition of scn_Auth could be: `val scn_Auth = scenario("authentication").exec(scn_Token1).exec(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Gatling can't pass data between users - if you need to execute scn_Token before each scn_Auth request to set a session parameter, just include it in scn_Token.

Redefine scn_Auth to be

```
  val scn_Auth ={ scenario("Authentication")
.exec(scn_Token1)
.exec(actionBuilder = http("Authentication")
  .post(authServiceUrl)
  .header("Token", "${Token}")
  .header("id", "${id}")
  .header("otp", "${otp}")
  .body(StringBody(bdy_Auth)).asJson
  .check(status.is(200)))
  .pause(tnk_Auth milliseconds)
}
```

and then only inject users for scn_Auth

Comment: I have similar question, now lets say I want to run the  exec(actionBuilder = http("Authentication") 10 times how do I do it ? basically I want to run exec(scn_Token1) once and exec(actionBuilder = http("Authentication") 10 times